# WSO2 Cluster Manager - Not all the members of the Group ,are shown as members in the Group of Cluster Manager feature. in WSO2 greg cluster uI

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Setup :Linux machines

WSO2 cluster manager: WSO2 Greg is enabled as cluster manager, by enabling group management with application domain 'ESB, where the 4 ESBs servers are enabled with cluster

4 ESB servers are :
1)WS02 ESB - Master - xx.xx.xxx.65 - master.esb.wso2.com
axis2.xml

```
<clustering class="org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.TribesClusteringAgent" enable="true">
<parameter name="membershipScheme">wka</parameter>
<parameter name="domain">ESB</parameter>
<members></members>
```

2)WS02 ESB - Slave1 -xx.xx.xxx.101 -slave1.esb.wso2.com
axis2.xml

```
<clustering class="org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.TribesClusteringAgent" enable="true">
<parameter name="membershipScheme">wka</parameter>
<parameter name="domain">ESB</parameter>
<members>
<member>
    <hostName>egreg.wso2.com</hostName>
    <port>4000</port>
</member>
<member>
    <hostName>master.esb.wso2.com</hostName>
    <port>4001</port>
</member>
</members>
```

3)WS02 ESB - Slave2 -xx.xx.xxx.22
axis2.xml

```
<clustering class="org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.TribesClusteringAgent" enable="true">
<parameter name="membershipScheme">wka</parameter>
<parameter name="domain">ESB</parameter>
<members>
<member>
    <hostName>egreg.wso2.com</hostName>
    <port>4000</port>
</member>
<member>
    <hostName>master.esb.wso2.com</hostName>
    <port>4001</port>
</member>
</members>
```

4)WS02 ESB - Slave3 - xx.xx.xxx.23
axis2.xml

```
<clustering class="org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.TribesClusteringAgent" enable="true">
<parameter name="membershipScheme">wka</parameter>
<parameter name="domain">ESB</parameter>
<members>
<member>
    <hostName>egreg.wso2.com</hostName>
    <port>4000</port>
</member>
<member>
    <hostName>master.esb.wso2.com</hostName>
    <port>4001</port>
</member>
</members>
```

WSO2 Greg where cluster manager feature is enabled to show the domain group ESB:
xx.xx.xxx.64 - egreg.wso2.com

```
<clustering class="org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.TribesClusteringAgent" enable="true">
<parameter name="membershipScheme">wka</parameter>
<parameter name="domain">CM</parameter>
<members>/<members>
<groupManagement enable="true">
        <applicationDomain name="ESB"
                           description="ESBs clustered"                                     agent="org.apache.axis2.clustering.management.DefaultGroupManagementAgent"/>
    </groupManagement>
```

This set up should basically show, all the 4 members of domain ESB under cluster feature of Greg UI, but I am faced with an error where only 2 members are shown and the other 2 are not shown

Servers slave2.esb.wso2.com and slave3.esb.wso2.com are shown as members under the GROUP/DOMAIN ESB in Cluster Manager feature UI in WSO2 GREG, but the other 2 servers master.esb.wso2.com and slave1.esb.wso2.com are not shown

I face the below error
2013-08-31 08:34:59,549]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Server           :  WSO2 Governance Registry-4.1.1
[2013-08-31 08:34:59,549]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  WSO2 Carbon started in 37 sec
[2013-08-31 08:36:35,542]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.clustering.control.wka.RpcMembershipRequestHandler} -  Received JOIN message from xx.xx.xxx.65:4000(ESB)
[2013-08-31 08:36:35,544]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.MembershipManager} -  Application member xx.xx.xxx.65:4000(ESB) joined group ESB
[2013-08-31 08:36:38,526]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.clustering.control.wka.RpcMembershipRequestHandler} -  Received MEMBER_LIST message from xx.xx.xxx.65:4000(ESB)
[2013-08-31 08:36:38,527]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.clustering.control.wka.MemberListCommand} -  Trying to add member xx.xx.xxx.65:4000(ESB)...
[2013-08-31 08:36:38,527]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.clustering.control.wka.MemberListCommand} -  Added member xx.xx.xxx.65:4000(ESB)
[2013-08-31 08:36:40,417]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.MembershipManager} -  A WKA member xx.xx.xxx.65:4000(CM) just joined the group. Sending MEMBER_LIST message.
[2013-08-31 08:36:50,416]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.TribesMembershipListener} -  New member xx.xx.xxx.65:4000(CM) joined cluster.
[2013-08-31 08:37:05,596] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.clustering.management.DefaultGroupManagementAgent} -  **Could not add application member Host:xx.xx.xxx.65, Port: 4000, HTTP:8280, HTTPS:8243, ACTIVE:true
[2013-08-31 08:37:16,220]  INFO** {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin' logged in at [2013-08-31 08:37:16,0220] from IP address xx.xx.xxx.xx
[2013-08-31 08:39:13,239]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.clustering.control.wka.RpcMembershipRequestHandler} -  Received JOIN message from xx.xx.xxx.101:4000(ESB)
[2013-08-31 08:39:13,239]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.MembershipManager} -  Application member xx.xx.xxx.101:4000(ESB) joined group ESB
[2013-08-31 08:39:15,726]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.MembershipManager} -  A WKA member xx.xx.xxx.101:4000(CM) just joined the group. Sending MEMBER_LIST message.
[2013-08-31 08:39:25,725]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.TribesMembershipListener} -  New member xx.xx.xxx.101:4000(CM) joined cluster.
[2013-08-31 08:39:43,291] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.clustering.management.DefaultGroupManagementAgent} -  **Could not add application member Host:xx.xx.xxx.101, Port: 4000, HTTP:8280, HTTPS:8243, ACTIVE:true
[2013-08-31 08:42:13,121]  INFO** {org.apache.axis2.clustering.control.wka.RpcMembershipRequestHandler} -  Received JOIN message from xx.xx.xxx.22:4000(ESB)
[2013-08-31 08:42:13,121]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.MembershipManager} -  Application member xx.xx.xxx.22:4000(ESB) joined group ESB
[2013-08-31 08:42:15,839]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.MembershipManager} -  A WKA member xx.xx.xxx.22:4000(CM) just joined the group. Sending MEMBER_LIST message.
[2013-08-31 08:42:23,130]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.clustering.management.DefaultGroupManagementAgent} -  **Application member Host:xx.xx.xxx.22, Port: 4000, HTTP:8280, HTTPS:8243, ACTIVE:true joined application cluster
[2013-08-31 08:42:25,841]  INFO** {org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.TribesMembershipListener} -  New member xx.xx.xxx.22:4000(CM) joined cluster.
[2013-08-31 08:43:21,959]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.clustering.control.wka.RpcMembershipRequestHandler} -  Received JOIN message from xx.xx.xxx.23:4000(ESB)
[2013-08-31 08:43:21,959]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.MembershipManager} -  Application member xx.xx.xxx.23:4000(ESB) joined group ESB
[2013-08-31 08:43:25,889]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.MembershipManager} -  A WKA member xx.xx.xxx.23:4000(CM) just joined the group. Sending MEMBER_LIST message.
[2013-08-31 08:43:31,964]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.clustering.management.DefaultGroupManagementAgent} -  **Application member Host:xx.xx.xxx.23, Port: 4000, HTTP:8280, HTTPS:8243, ACTIVE:true joined application cluster
[2013-08-31 08:43:35,890]  INFO** {org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.TribesMembershipListener} -  New member xx.xx.xxx.23:4000(CM) joined cluster.

I would appreciate quick response, as I am planning this set up in a PROD machine.

Could anyone from wso2 team, please let me know as what could be the reason, behind this error?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WKA membership scheme, you have to specify the host names and the ports of all the members who will be joining the cluster. Instead you have specified only the master and the greg.

But you ideally need to specify all the masters and workers hosts and ports under members element.

Hope I have resolved your concern. 
Manisha

Comment: Thanks for replying. From what I can understand , you seem to be suggesting to specify all the master and workers host and ports under member element, of all the servers(master, slave1, slave2,slave3) ?Did I get you right?